# Reading a .txt file with javascript and update it at an interval

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a .txt file on my server. I need a script to read it in an infinite loop, at every 500ms. Basically, that variable should be updated every 500ms and displayed on a .php page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: setInterval to call the ajax function to do whatever you want

Comment: You can manipulate files using php as well, maybe you should into that.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for reading the text file;

`readTextFile("file:///C:/your/path/to/file.txt")`;

```
function readTextFile(file)
    {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                {
                    var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    alert(allText);
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `setTimeout` because request maybe waits a long time.If you want no waiting use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` but give heed to ram usage.

```
var currentText=null;

var getText=function(){
$.ajax({
        url: "http://www.sample-videos.com/text/Sample-text-file-10kb.txt",
        success: function (r) { currentText=r;alert(currentText);setTimeout(getText,500); },
        error: function () { alert('it doesnt work') }
    });}

setTimeout(getText,500)
```